# htaccess URL Rewrite for Isotope & Infinite Scroll Load More

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, jquery-isotope, infinite-scroll

I am trying to create a page that loads data via PHP & MySQL, and display the posts with Isotope & Infinite Scroll, as well as using `.htaccess` to rewrite to clean URLs.

When the user scrolls down, Infinite Scroll loads data from a second PHP MySQL script (separate file) and appends them to the previous Isotope elements, which works perfectly on the index/front page:

```
$('#isotope').infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : 'div.pagination', 
    nextSelector : 'div.pagination a:first', 
    itemSelector : '.post',
    bufferPx : 20,
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: 'No more items.'
    }
},

function( newElements ) {
    var $newElems = jQuery( newElements ).hide(); 
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $newElems.fadeIn();
        $container.isotope( 'appended', $newElems );
    });
});
```

The issue I have is with the `.htaccess` URL rewrites:

Let's say for a page called `blog-posts.php`, where I would like to change the URL to a clean one `http://website.com/blog-posts`.

I can load the first set of data into the page via PHP (from eg. a file called `blog-posts.php`), and display them in the Isotope layout, it works perfectly.

However, when the user scrolls down, the second set of data (from eg. a file called `blog-posts-load-more.php`), it doesn't load into the page, and is not appended to Isotope.

The data is loaded via trigger link on the main blog-posts.php page:

```
<a href="blog-posts-load-more.php?posttype=<?php echo $posttype;?>"></a>
```

The blog-posts-load-more.php file then calls a simple MySQL statement:

```
$posttype = $_GET['posttype'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posttype='$posttype'"; 
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die (mysqli_error());
```

When I call the file in the browser separately via `http://website.com/blog-posts-load-more.php` then the data appears. Something seems to break in my `.htaccess` rewrite?

```
RewriteRule blog-posts blog-posts.php [NC,L]
```

I have also tried the following version (since my blog-posts-load.more.php is using $_GET variables:

```
RewriteRule blog-posts/(.*)/ blog-posts.php?posttype=$1 [NC,L]
```

What am I doing wrong? I am using the same script as on the `index.php` page, where it works perfectly.

Comment: Maybe the problem is not in htaccess. Does the page get called via XHR? Besides, it seems like you are talking about the wrong rewritten page: either blog-posts-load-more.php doesn't match your rule, or the rule generates a rewrite loop because both blog-posts.php and blog-posts match.

Comment: I noticed that when Infinite Scroll tries to load more content, it says "loading..." for a second but then jumps straight to "there are no more posts to load" message, ie. the second PHP file doesn't load any data from MySQL ?

Comment: You have to check -and possibly report here :) - what's happening "behind the scene", using a tool like Firebug or the Developer tools (press F12 if you are on a PC), under the "network tab". Does the page really get called? Is there any javascript/html error like "page not found" or "internal server error"?

Comment: It says status response "200 ok". It does work when I use the normal .php extensions, but as soon as I start messing with the .htaccess rewrites, it stops working ...

Comment: What do you mean by "stops working"? Do you get any error code in firebug/dev. tools? If so it may be a server config problem.

Comment: No error, I still get "200 ok" status in Firebug for the load-more.php call, but Infinite Scroll puts out "no more posts" and does not display any new posts. As soon as I use the normal ".php?posttype=" URL it works, it just messes up when I fiddle with the .htaccess rewrites

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58619/discussion-between-paolo-stefan-and-rainerbrunotte).